# Quagga bgp advertisment stop after peer restart

Tags: routing, bgp

I am using quagga and FreeBSD boxes to achieve this: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13762-40.html#conf3. Only change is that upstream provider is sending full bgp instead of the default route.

I have everything set up and working moreless correctly. However, I am having issues with few things:

- when connection between R101 and R103 goes down, R101 doesn't send traffic over R102-R104 link. This is because, R101 doesn't have any routes R102 besides the one I am advertising. How should I can configure quagga to redistribute routes obtained via external peer over internal BGP session?
- For advertising my networks, Quagga works until the moment I restart R101. Once, R!01 comes back and internal BGP session is re-established, R102 stops advertising anything to R101, but advertises to R104. Is this normal? After I restart quagga on R102, the advertising to R101 works correctly.

Quagga config from R101:

```
!
hostname Router
log file /var/log/quagga.log
log stdout
hostname bgpd
bgp config-type cisco
!
debug bgp updates in
!
password zebra
enable password zebra
!
interface bge0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface bge1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb2
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lagg0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lo0
 no link-detect
!
interface lo1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface pfsync0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan4
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan5
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan101
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan106
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan107
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan109
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
router bgp 1
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 0.0.0.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.0.0.0
 network 2.0.0.0
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 remote-as 2
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 description "R101 uplink"
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 update-source 4.4.4.2
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 send-community both
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 route-map R1-MAP out
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 1
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 description "R101 BGP interconnect"
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source 1.1.1.2
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 send-community both
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 maximum-paths 2
 no auto-summary
!
ip prefix-list 1 seq 5 permit 2.0.0.0/8
ip prefix-list 2 seq 5 permit 1.0.0.0/8
!
route-map R1-MAP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list 1
 set as-path prepend 1 1 1
!
route-map R1-MAP permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list 2
!
ip forwarding
!
line vty
!
end
```

R102 full config:

```
hostname Router
hostname bgpd
log file /var/log/quagga.log
log stdout
bgp config-type cisco
!
password zebra
enable password zebra
!
interface bge0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface bge1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb2
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lagg0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lo0
 no link-detect
!
interface lo1
 no link-detect
!
interface pfsync0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan4
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan5
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan101
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan106
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan107
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan109
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
router bgp 1
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 0.0.0.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.0.0.0
 network 2.0.0.0
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 remote-as 2
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 description "R102 uplink"
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 update-source 3.3.3.2
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 send-community both
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 route-map R102-MAP out
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 remote-as 1
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 description "R102 BGP interconnect"
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 update-source 1.1.1.1
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 send-community both
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 no auto-summary
!
ip prefix-list 1 seq 5 permit 1.0.0.0/8
ip prefix-list 2 seq 5 permit 2.0.0.0/8
!
route-map R102-MAP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list 1
 set as-path prepend 1 1 1
!
route-map R102-MAP permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list 2
!
ip forwarding
!
line vty
!
end
```

Comment: Can you made a "sho ip bgp" on R101 and R102??, You can put here the major of your configuration, on the way to clear our doubts about your conf.

Comment: I you can, also put R103 and R104 conf.

Comment: I don't have access to R103 and R104 (it's on provider's side). I will paste the configs shortly. "sho ip bgp" shows full bgp routing tablee.

Comment: Oh, i see, i was thinking that your conf was only for testing purpose. We will be expecting.

Comment: I have some things like AS number, peer IPs etc replaced with faked, which should be OK.

Comment: What about your "sho ip bgp". Are you receiving a "default route" by the two links??

Comment: I am not receiving the default as the provider is sending full bgp instead.

Comment: Oh, i see. Then, on your "sho ip bgp", do you only receive the routes from one neighbor then??

Comment: No, I receive routes from both R103 and R102. But when I restart R101, R102 stops sending routes to R101 (I see nothing in "sh ip bgp neigh IP advertised-routes"..

Comment: When you said, "restart", you mean the quagga daemon, the bgpd daemon, the bgp session with it peers or the linux inself??

Comment: Server reboot, operating system.

Comment: One comment. I´m very interesting on the reason why on your "sho run", did not appears your interfaces configuration(unless you had delete it).

Comment: I am using quagga only for bgp, interface configuration is done in system configuration. Networking itself works correctly, I have issues with quagga when I reboot one server.

Comment: Ok, and your bgp session goes UP once your restart??

Comment: Yes, it comes up.

Comment: On wich moment is when your configuration works fine,.. eg: when all bgp sessions are "entablished" and your are receiving routes from iBGP and eBGP??

Comment: yes, the case you describe. If I reboot r101 in that moment, r102 stops advertising my routes to r101 once in comes back.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

By the data that you give us, this one is an interesting part. Unless you had change the neighbors for your safety, and put the conf here, i think you need to explaind why your iBGP neighbor has the same IP address of your UPDATE SOURCE? This one is like if your iBGP share your same host.

```
neighbor 1.1.1.1 description "R101 BGP interconnect"
neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source 1.1.1.1
neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
neighbor 1.1.1.1 send-community both
neighbor 1.1.1.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound

neighbor 1.1.1.2 description "R102 BGP interconnect"
neighbor 1.1.1.2 update-source 1.1.1.2
neighbor 1.1.1.2 next-hop-self
neighbor 1.1.1.2 send-community both
neighbor 1.1.1.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
```

Comment: I am sorry, this was a mistake on my part. I double checked before posting the config. I actually changed the config for safety reason. It's supposed to be inverted. I'll fix it in the config.